# Projeto no Android studio não roda por falta de libs

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou com esse erro ao tentar rodar um projeto Android que fiz a um tempo atrás, clonei o repositório do git e tentei rodar, atualizei o Android Studio a pouco tempo não sei o que fazer.

Erro:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/geovanni/Documentos/UnB/2016.2/TecProg/TrabalhoTecProg/EuVou/app/libs/*.jar
>   (Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os projetos do Android Studio usam o Gradle para fazer o build. Veja se no arquivo `build.gradle` existe a declaração para ele utilizar os jars da pasta libs como dependência. Geralmente como abaixo:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}
```